# AVCaptureSession with Autolayout

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, ios-autolayout

I have a strange problem,

In My app I'm running a background video (via `AVCaptureSession`) and the application is for iPhone Devices so it needs to fit multiple screens via autolayout. 
The problem is if I setup the session into `ViewDidLoad` the frames still didn't set and if I setup the session into `viewDidLayoutSubviews` the session stop running and the application crashes.

Here is my AVCaptureSession Code

```
- (void)setupAVCapture {
    //Capture session
    _session = nil;
    _session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [_session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetLow];

    //Get the camera and set the capture device
    AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice = [self getCamera:_camera]; // self.camera

    //Capture device input
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:nil];
    if ([_session canAddInput:deviceInput])
        [_session addInput:deviceInput];

    //Capture Still Image Output
    stillImageOutput = nil;
    stillImageOutput = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput new];
    [stillImageOutput addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"capturingStillImage" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:(__bridge void *)(AVCaptureStillImageIsCapturingStillImageContext)];
    if ([_session canAddOutput:stillImageOutput])
    {
        [_session addOutput:stillImageOutput];
    }

    //Capture Video Data Output
    videoDataOutput = nil;
    videoDataOutput = [AVCaptureVideoDataOutput new];

    NSDictionary *rgbOutputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
    [videoDataOutput setVideoSettings:rgbOutputSettings];
    [videoDataOutput setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];

    videoDataOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("VideoDataOutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    [videoDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:videoDataOutputQueue];

    if ([_session canAddOutput:videoDataOutput])
    {
        [_session addOutput:videoDataOutput];
    }

    [[videoDataOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setEnabled:NO];

    //preview view
    self.previewLayer = nil;
    self.previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:_session];
    [self.previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

    CALayer *rootLayer = [_previewView layer];
    [rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [[[self previewLayer]connection]setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
    //[self.previewLayer setTransform:CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2))];
    [self.previewLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, rootLayer.bounds.size.width, rootLayer.bounds.size.height)];
    [rootLayer insertSublayer:self.previewLayer atIndex:0];

    //go
    [_session startRunning];

    AVCaptureDevicePosition desiredPosition = [[self getCamera:_camera] position];//AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;

    for (AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice in [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo])
    {
        if ([captureDevice position] == desiredPosition)
        {
            [[_previewLayer session] beginConfiguration];
            AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:nil];

            for (AVCaptureInput *oldInput in [[_previewLayer session] inputs])
            {
                [[_previewLayer session] removeInput:oldInput];
            }

            [[_previewLayer session] addInput:input];
            [[_previewLayer session] commitConfiguration];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahah, that's funny, I've came through that issue yesterday, with the same crash.
So actually, even if it doesn't look like so, you are running that code in background. You should clearly tell that you want to add layers on the main thread, especially these three lines of code :

```
    [self.previewLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, rootLayer.bounds.size.width, rootLayer.bounds.size.height)];
    [rootLayer insertSublayer:self.previewLayer atIndex:0];
    [_session startRunning];
```

do this instead :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [self.previewLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, rootLayer.bounds.size.width, rootLayer.bounds.size.height)];
  [rootLayer insertSublayer:self.previewLayer atIndex:0];
  [_session startRunning];
});
```

Hope this will help ;)

Comment: I still got 
malloc: *** error for object 0x17004e820: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: ok so try to run the session in viewDidAppear to see if it comes from the layout

Comment: It seems that the problem caused by XCode 8.0 beta 4, I built a project on XCode 7.3.1 and it works fine

Comment: Yeah I've noted the same thing, but the answer I gave was a sort of a fix that worked for me :)